# Java map.get(map.put(String, boolean)), what is its meaning?

Tags: java, dictionary, hashmap

I am following a tutorial and I met these instructions:

```
public class WorldController {
    enum Keys {
        LEFT,
        RIGHT,
        JUMP,
        FIRE
    }

    private World world;

    static Map<Keys, Boolean> keys = new HashMap<Keys, Boolean>();
    static {
        keys.put(Keys.LEFT, false);
        keys.put(Keys.RIGHT, false);
        keys.put(Keys.JUMP, false);
        keys.put(Keys.FIRE, false);
    };

    public WorldController(World world) {
        this.world = world;
    }

    // ** Key presses and touches **************** //
    public void leftPressed() {
        keys.get(keys.put(Keys.LEFT, true));
    }
    public void rightPressed() {
        keys.get(keys.put(Keys.RIGHT, true));
    }
    public void jumpPressed() {
        keys.get(keys.put(Keys.JUMP, true));
    }
    public void firePressed() {
        keys.get(keys.put(Keys.FIRE, false));
    }

    public void leftReleased() {
        keys.get(keys.put(Keys.LEFT, false));
    }
    public void rightReleased() {
        keys.get(keys.put(Keys.RIGHT, false));
    }
    public void jumpReleased() {
        keys.get(keys.put(Keys.JUMP, false));
    }
    public void fireReleased() {
        keys.get(keys.put(Keys.FIRE, false));
    }
}
```

As I can see the methods `leftPressed()`, `rightPressed()`, etc return nothing. Is there any particular reason why it puts and immediately gets the value (without returning it)?

Comment: No, this doesn't do anything in particular.

Comment: your functions are of type `void` what did you expect it to return

Comment: I want to understand why the author of that code wrote those instructions, I want nothing

Comment: Without seeing the tutorial I have to assume the author doesn't know what they're doing.

Comment: It is a tutorial on libgdx (chapter Processing Input – on Desktop & Android), the author seems to be skilled, http://obviam.net/index.php/getting-started-in-android-game-development-with-libgdx-create-a-working-prototype-in-a-day-tutorial-part-1/

Comment: You might want to post the full context so we can understand it better.

Comment: I posted the code of the tutorial. It needs to map the currently pressed keys, than it puts the keys into a map (in order to know in each moment what if a key is pressed or not)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you see the docs for

```
V put(K key, V value);
```

method of Map class it says return value represents the previous value associated with key, or null if there was no mapping for key.

So when you execute say

```
public void methodAtrue() {
    myMap.get(myMap.put("A", true));
}
```

You know you are setting the value of key "A" to true. Also this function will return previous value associated with the key "A". And the you are performing `get()` on the return value which us `boolean`(null if no mapping existed prior to put).

Since you have Map as

```
 Map<Keys, Boolean> keys = new HashMap<Keys, Boolean>();
```

you cannot use `get(Boolean)`. You need to use `get(Keys)`.

Comment: I am not the author of that code, I would just like to know if that code makes sense (and what is its sense if it has one)

Comment: No it does not make any sense as it is incorrect. It will not even compile. As I said you cannot use `get(Boolean)`. You need to use `get(Keys)`.

Comment: It compiles (the get method wants an Object, not necessarily a Keys)

Comment: It compiles but gives me following warning `Map<Keys,Boolean> may not contain keys of type Boolean`. It is guaranteed to fail at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

The tutorial likely intended to return all of those get methods, as they don't do anything in their current state.

Alternatively, the author was demonstrating how the get method of a map works, and was simply showing what they would return without doing anything with it.